# Flex Accessing OS System Icons

Tags: apache-flex, file, operating-system, icons, native

Hi does anyone know I can display the icon of a file that has been associated with that file in the native OS.

I have a tile list of a folder's contents.  For images, I display the image, for everything else I display a generic image.  However, it would be great if I could tap into the OS and just use the icon that the OS uses. For example, if I have installed Microsoft Word on my computer, then when I view a word document in the file system it will display the word icon that Microsoft created for word documents.  For MP3's it might be an iTunes type sound icon, if I have iTunes installed and so on.

Basically, for all the files in my tile list I want to just show the same icon that Windows, or Mac OS would etc.

In addition to this, if the OS creates a thumbnail for the file (images, videos and PDFs for example) is it possible to tap into this OS generated thumb?

Cheers,

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write OS-dependent tools that will grab native icons (EXE for Win, DMG for Mac, etc.) and package them with your application into a native installer.

After this you will be able to call those native tools from you AIR app.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.  Do have any code examples I could use?  Your answer sounds strategically good, but I could with some more information.  Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately no examples. It may worth asking corresponding questions in Mac and Win native apps sections.

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for the same question and i came upon this [Displaying native icons in AIR](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/stevencarpenter/entry/air_using_native/). In that link, there is sample code for rendering native system icons.

Hope this will be useful.